# Python / Django compare and update model objects

Tags: python, django, csv, multiprocessing

Iv only just started python but have learned a lot over the last few month, now I have hit a wall about updating objects on a model at a good speed.

I have a model called Products and this is populated from a csv file, every day this file get updated with changes like cost, and quantity, I can compare each line of the file with the Products Model but having 120k lines this takes 3-4hours.

What process can I take to make this process this file faster.  I only want to modify the objects if cost and quantity have changed

Any suggestions how I tackle this?

Ver3 of what i have tried.

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from multiprocessing import Pool
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pprint import pprint  
from CentralControl.models import Product, Supplier
from CentralControl.management.helpers.map_ingram import *
from CentralControl.management.helpers.helper_generic import *
from tqdm import tqdm

from CentralControl.management.helpers.config import get_ingram
import os, sys, csv, zipfile, CentralControl

# Run Script as 'SYSTEM'
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

# Get Connection config.   
SUPPLIER_CODE, FILE_LOCATION, FILE_NAME = get_ingram()


class Command(BaseCommand):
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    list_in = get_file()
    list_current = get_current_list()

    pool = Pool(6)

    pool.map(compare_lists(list_in, list_current))

    pool.close()



def compare_lists(list_in, list_current):
    for row_current in tqdm(list_current):
         for row_in in list_in:
             if row_in['order_code'] == row_current['order_code']:

                #do more stuff here.

                pass

def get_current_list():
    try:
        supplier = Supplier.objects.get(code='440040')
        current_list = Product.objects.filter(supplier=supplier).values()
        return current_list
    except:
        print('Error no products with supplier')
        exit()


def get_file():
    with zipfile.ZipFile(FILE_LOCATION + 'incoming/' + FILE_NAME, 'r') as zip:
    with zip.open('228688 .csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        list_in = (list(reader))

        for row in tqdm(list_in):
            row['order_code'] = row.pop('Ingram Part Number')
            row['order_code'] = (row['order_code']).lstrip("0")
            row['name'] = row.pop('Ingram Part Description')
            row['description'] = row.pop('Material Long Description')
            row['mpn'] = row.pop('Vendor Part Number')
            row['gtin'] = row.pop('EANUPC Code')
            row['nett_cost'] = row.pop('Customer Price')
            row['retail_price'] = row.pop('Retail Price')
            row['qty_at_supplier'] = row.pop('Available Quantity')
            row['backorder_date'] = row.pop('Backlog ETA')
            row['backorder_date'] = (row['backorder_date'])
            row['backorder_qty'] = row.pop('Backlog Information')

        zip.close()
        #commented out for dev precess.
        #os.rename(FILE_LOCATION + 'incoming/' + FILE_NAME, FILE_LOCATION + 'processed/' + FILE_NAME)
        return list_in
```

Comment: How can we improve the efficiency of code we've never seen? Post what you have done and let's see where it's wrong

Comment: You can use hashing to quickly compare two objects for differences. You can use this to accelerate the object comparison. An alternative would be to compare each days csv file and extract only the lines which have changed for update.

Comment: `120k lines this takes 3-4hours.` You are certainly expecting too much. It can't take this much time. If you have so much data to process than i would suggest using some task runners like celery.

Answer (score 0):

I have once faced a problem of slow load of data, I can tell you what i did maybe it can help you somehow, I passed the execution to debug mode and tried to find out wich colomn is causing the slow loading, and everytime i see that a colomn is causing the problem I add an index on it (in the SGBD --> postgreSQL in my case), and it worked. I hope that you are facing the same problem so my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's rough idea:
1, when reading csv, use pandas as suggest by @BearBrow into array_csv
2, convert the obj data from Django into Numpy Arrary  array_obj
3, don't compare them one by one , using numpy substraction

```
compare_index = (array_csv[['cost',['quantity']]] - array[['cost',['quantity']]] == 0)
```

4, find the updated column
   obj_need_updated = array_obj[np.logic_any(compare_index['cost'], compare['quantity'])]

then use Django bulk update https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update to bulk update

Hope this will give you hints to speed up your code

Comment: Giving this a crack.  but getting an error.

`code`
    def get_file():
        with zipfile.ZipFile(FILE_LOCATION + 'incoming/' + FILE_NAME, 'r') as zip:
            with zip.open('228688 .csv') as csvfile:
                list_in = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
                print(list_in)

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 40 fields in line 33967, saw 41

Comment: @flammable  it seems the data in 228688.csv is not consistent,  you can check line line 33967,  the error said that line has 41 fields while other line has 40 fields

Comment: So I have both in arrays now, just need to learn how to compare different fields per product_code.

Comment: @flammable  if the fields you need to compare are numbers or floats, numpy serials can easy compare them in bulk by subtraction, then locate the zero lines and its line number. i suggest you can practice numpy with just intro documents :)