# Python / Django Compare Specific Column in two Lists

Tags: python, django, csv, models

Im re-asking this question as I failed to provide a real outline of what I want to do. [Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540883/python-django-compare-and-update-model-objects)

I have a CSV list that I need to import daily and compare some columns to what I have stored in my Django Model. [order_code],[cost_price],[quantity](there are more details, not none that I need to compare).

I only want to update the Django obj if the [cost_price], and/or [quantity] has changed.

I can already do this by turning my csv in to a list and then working down that list and compare it against the obj, in the model. How ever this take far to much time when daily I want to check 120k records.

I understand that there are some better way to do this, by filtering my results from the Models and dropping out the current items from that supplier in to a list, and then compare the two list in memory instead of calling the Model for every line.

I guess at the end I want to create 3 lists,

1) Items needing updates(existing products that need [cost_price],[quantity] updated).
2) Items that need created (new products).
3) Items that did not exist in the updated csv, as I need to deactivate theses(I have a status field on my model.)

..Then I can run 3 bulk processes.

The reason why I just don't bulk update every day is that I have a process that records a modify date, and my app then messages only updates to 3 other external services.

So now I guess my question what is the fastest way to compare current, with updates list. Keeping in mind what I have said above.

Columns are not called that same, or in the same order. But I do know the names.